# Infinite series approximation of pi in C not terminating

Tags: c, pi, approximation

Here is my code, when using print statements it appeared to be an infinite loop:

some potential issues i can troubleshoot are integer division, and perhaps figuring out if the algorithm terminates, and if it always has the correct output, perhaps there is some idiosyncrasy of the C language that I do not understand causing this issue?

From my understanding as the sum tends to negative infinity it will cause the break statement to be triggered ending the algorithm once it reaches an approximation of epsilon precision.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

  double pi, sum, epsilon;
  long long i=1;
  long long max = 2147483647;
  printf("Pleas enter the desired accuracy epsilon : ");
  scanf("%f", &epsilon);
  while (i<max){
    if (i%2 == 0){
      sum = -4.0/(2.0*i-1);
    }else if (i%2 ==1){
      sum = (4.0/(2.0*i-1));
    }
    if (sum < epsilon){
      break;
    }
    pi += sum;
  }
  printf("The value of pi approximated to epsion : %f is %f\n", epsilon, pi);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never increased `i`

Comment: Use a `for` loop instead, then such mistakes are easier to find.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, i added the increment within the loop, however it appears the final awnser is still 4.0, i will continue to troubleshoot.

Comment: If you're using C99 or newer, `printf` `%lf` is pointless (it's equivalent to `%f`). If you're using C90, `printf` `%lf` has undefined behavior.

Comment: @melpomene I have got the algorithm working, however I need to display more than the 6 digits standard with double, how would you recommend doing that

Comment: How many digits do you need?

Comment: I just used %20.18f for 18 digits of precision, is that common/accurate for floating point arithmetic?

Comment: Please read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Please stop changing your question in a way that invalidates existing answers.

Comment: Read also the documentation of every function you are using, notably of [scanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) and of [printf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/printf). Read http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Do not edit the question to [invalidate existing answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290704/3956566)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not increment the value of `i` in your `while` loop. As a result its value always remains 1.

Increment `i` after your processing is done before the closing `}` of the `while` loop.

Initialize the values of `pi, sum, epsilon` so that you do not run into undefined behavior when you try to read their values for the first time.

Also, with proper options enabled (`-Wall` with GCC) the compiler will warn you, that you are trying to read a `float` into a `double`.

```
warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'float *', but argument 2 has type 'double *' [-Wformat=]

   scanf("%f", &epsilon);

          ~^   ~~~~~~~~
```

So you have to use the correct conversion specifier: `%lf` instead of `%f` in your `scanf` statement.

If you are not very particular about the number `2147483647` and just want a large value, you can also use `ULLONG_MAX` (from `limits.h`) to initialize `max` instead of hard-coding the value.

Comment: `ULLONG_MAX` is guaranteed not to be `2147483647`.

Comment: the arithmetic is still not working properly however

Comment: @BenFrench: Have you initialized `pi, sum, epsilon` at the beginning?

Comment: yeah i have initialized it and fixed the arithmetic, its working now, however it only displays to 6 decimal places, i am working on extending the floating point decimals displayed, thanks for your help so far though

Answer (score 1):

You need to increment `i` value in `while` loop.

Your looping condition `while(i < max)` is always satisfied (infinite loop). So the value of `i` or `max` should be changed inside the loop to ever end the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has undefined behavior:

```
scanf("%f", &epsilon);
```

`scanf` `%f` takes a `float *`, not `double *`. The correct format for `double *` is `%lf`.

---

Your loop condition `while (i<max)` is equivalent to `while (1)` as neither `i` nor `max` change their value inside the loop.

This also means `sum` is always `4`:

```
sum = (4.0/(2.0*i-1));
// 4 / (2 * 1 - 1) = 4 / (2 - 1) = 4 / 1 = 4
```

---

```
pi += sum;
```

also has undefined behavior: `pi` is uninitialized.

Comment: yeah, it appears that sum is always 4, correct, I will try to fix this